# Why X- Axis is sorted alphabetically in geom_line

Tags: r

here is an example of my data:

```
test = data.frame(month_year = c("MAR13","APR13","MAY13","JUN13"),
                  turnover = c(10,15,25,10))
```

Here is my plot:

```
ggplot(data = test,
       aes(x = month_year,
       y = turnover,
       group = 1))+
  geom_line()
```

Now my question is why is the X-axis sorted alphabetically and how can I prevent it, because as you can see it makes no sense.

Thank you!

Comment: `month_year` is a factor and is sorted alphanumerically. Coerce it to ordered factor et voila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use :

```
test = data.frame(month_year = factor(c("MAR13","APR13","MAY13","JUN13"),levels=c("MAR13","APR13","MAY13","JUN13")),
              turnover = c(10,15,25,10))
```

[image]